# ERROR: The puppet master service failed to start within 120 seconds; unable to proceed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, puppet-enterprise

I'm trying to install puppet-enterprise (2016.1.1) on EC2 in AWS. It keeps failing all the time by showing the error message below :

```
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140
** HTTP_PROXY= http_proxy= HTTPS_PROXY= https_proxy= /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/curl --tlsv1 -f -s MY_EC2_INSTANCE_PUBLIC_HOSTNAME:8140

========================================================================
** cp /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/share/installer/install_log.lastrun.ec2-52-9-200-155.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.log /var/log/puppetlabs/installer
** sed "s/^\(q_.*password\)=.*/#\1=REDACTED/g" < "/tmp/pe-installer-M5BopSNZ/install/answers.lastrun.ec2-52-9-200-155.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" > "/var/log/puppetlabs/installer/answers.install"
!! ERROR: The puppet master service failed to start within 120
   seconds; unable to proceed
```

thanks,
your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. We must use at least an m3.large to install Puppet Enterprise.
Thanks to PuppetLabs.